# Unable to down load XLS file on with https on IE 8 but working fine withh other browser

Tags: ssl, https, internet-explorer-8, xls

I am unable to download xls file in Internet with SSL(https)
i am using following header information in jsp page.same is downloading fine with other browser.please help if i can add any thing extar in header information.

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache")
response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache")
response.setDateHeader ("Expires", 0)
```

Comment: So what does your browsers development console say about that download attempt?

Answer (score 0):

You can try these headers:

```
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="my_file.xls"
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Pragma: public
```

It works for me!